# Pegar dados do BD SQLite sem usar ListView

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Meu código precisa pegar os dados do banco de dados, em resumo só falta os seguintes comandos:

```
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Contato contato = new Contato();

    contato.setCodigo(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")));
    contato.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NOME")));
    contato.setTelefone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TELEFONE")));
    return contato;
} else 
    return null;
```

Queria saber se é possível pegar os dados do BD sem precisar usar *ListView* ou *Spinner* (usando apenas *TextView* em apenas um layout xml)! Por isso preciso pegar apenas dados de uma linha(*row*) específica de uma determinada tabela, que essa linha será informada pelo usuário!

Tenho vários contatos (nome, telefone, e-mail) no BD mas não quero exibir tipo todos os contatos do BD na `main.xml`, apenas tipo 1 contato informado pelo usuário! Alguém sabe tipo como pegar os dados da BD sem precisar disso:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacto_list_item, cursor, columns, to);
this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Ou seja, sem precisar agregar o layout `contacto_list_item.xml` no `main.xml`, pois na main não quero usar *ListView* ou *Spinner*!

Comment: Sim, é possível.

Comment: Como se faz isso? Vc tem algum link de algum tutorial?

Comment: tem esse: [Parte 1](http://pplware.sapo.pt/smartphones-tablets/android/tutorial-utilizao-do-sqlite-no-android-parte-i/) e [Parte 2](http://pplware.sapo.pt/smartphones-tablets/android/tutorial-utilizao-do-sqlite-no-android-parte-ii/)

Comment: Só para te orientar, o site aqui é um site de Perguntas e Respostas. Sua _pergunta_ não se adequa muito bem ao propósito do site, seria bom que você apresentasse um problema mais específico, o seu está muito abrangente. Por favor [faça um tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site ;)

Comment: Obg pelo tutorial, mas para exibir os contatos ele usa ListView no main.xml e é isso que não quero! Não quero exibir tipo todos os contatos do BD na main, apenas tipo 1 informado pelo usuário! Você sabe tipo como pegar os dados da BD sem precisar disso: "adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacto_list_item, 
                                       cursor, 
                                       columns, 
                                       to); 
                                       this.setListAdapter(adapter);"

Comment: Tipo quero pegar as informaçoes do BD de forma direta sem precisa tipo agregar o layout_model: contacto_list_item.xml no layout main.xml

Comment: opa, sua pergunta tá começando a ficar mais específica, legal.. talvez você devesse explicar melhor na sua pergunta, editando ela, ao invés de adicionar comentários

Comment: Ok,mas vc tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Não está muito claro o que você está perguntando...

Comment: Desculpe se não fui claro! Mas meu problema foi resolvido! Falta só esses comandos aqui: if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Contato contato = new Contato();

        contato.setCodigo(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")));
        contato.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NOME")));
        contato.setTelefone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TELEFONE")));
        return contato;
    } else 
        return null;

Comment: Se você encontrou a resposta deve postá-la como tal, utilizando o quadrado das resposta. Deve depois aceitá-la para ela deixe de constar na perguntas não respondidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que você possa trabalhar diretamente com os dados o SQLite utilizando o a função [Query do SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) ou a [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Basicamente será feita uma select no banco e retornado um [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) onde você pode trabalhar com os dados utilizando o [getInt(int columnIndex)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29), [getString(int columnIndex)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29), assim sucessivamente.

Para saber o index da coluna basta utilizar [getColumnIndex(String columnName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29)

Exemplo Básico:

```
public class Teste extends Activity {


public Contato carregarContato(String nomeContato){

    // Criado um DataBase Helper Simples apenas para fins didáticos.
    // Foi necessário fazer isso para ter acesso a uma instancia do banco de dados.
    SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(this, "nomebanco", null, 1) {

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CONTATO (  " 
            + "    ID INTEGER, " 
            + "    NOME VARCHAR( 100 ), " 
            + "    TELEFONE VARCHAR( 30 ) );");

        }
    };

    //Aqui começa o exemplo na prática
    Cursor cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().query("CONTATO", null, " NOME LIKE '%?%'", new String[]{nomeContato}, null, null, null);

    /** Quando abre o curso ele fica um posição antes do inicio. O moveToNext verifica se há registro.
        Se houver a necessidade de carregar uma lista coloque dentro de um while(cursor.moveToNext())
    */
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Contato contato = new Contato();

        contato.setCodigo(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")));
        contato.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NOME")));
        contato.setTelefone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TELEFONE")));
        return contato;
    } else 
        return null;
}


public class Contato {
    private int codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String telefone;
    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }



}
```

}

Claro que para implantar isso em produto você tem que fazer os tratamento e *exception* necessário para garantir o funcionamento correto.

Mais informação na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)